# How do I read a specific position in file in each line for C++?

Tags: c++, file

Sorry if this question sounds familiar, I just did not how to phrase it specifically, but what I want to do is pass for instance every sixth value in a row of a file into an array. But I’m not sure how to grab that specific value.

For example number.txt file contains:
Line 1: 1 6 7 8 7 9
Line2: 2 5 7 6 5 4

Say I want to grab 9 from first line and then grab 4 from the second line, how would I do that? Also, how would I grab only the first 5 elements in first line and second line, excluding the sixth one? Thanks.

Comment: You have to show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Step 1) identify individual lines. Step 2) identify individual offsets within a given line.

Answer (score 1):

You can set current input position for [`std::ifstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) with [`seekg`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg). But more practical solution would be to read all content and filter it inside your program.

Comment: For example, like putting all the values in an array first, and then from that array grabbing the specific value I want using a for loop to save it into another array? I thought about this method, but I was unsure.

Comment: @DiegoPadua, yes, something like that. You may want to use seek to work with really big files, but you need some way to know where to read. Usually it would mean that you will be reading a file in a binary format designed for that purpose.